# Limitation while generating excel drop down list with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to generate an excel file with some validations, I've read the [poi dev guides](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation) for implementing it.  During implementation, I got an exception (`String literals in formulas can't be bigger than 255 characters ASCII`). POI concatenates all drop down options into '0' deliminated string and checking its length and giving me exception. :(  
 I'm using latest version of POI 3.8 beta 5.

And my code is:

```
try {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    //CellRangeAddressList from org.apache.poi.ss.util package
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
    DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(getCountries());
    DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

After that I have tried with XSSFWorkBook with this code:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
DataValidationHelper validationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
DataValidationConstraint constraint = validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(getCountries());
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
DataValidation dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
dataValidation.setErrorStyle(DataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.xlsx");
```

Unfortunately, no success with such result which is comma delimenated long string in one cell:

[image]

But manually in excel, I can create dropdown cells with this long country list.
Is there any way generate dropdown with long strings, or API does not support?

Comment: sounds like a bug/limitation in the POI implementation, maybe you should rather report this as bug at http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I understood it, Excel itself does not allow entering validation range string more than 255 characters, this was not POI limitation. And now I'm using [Named Ranges and Named Cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges) and it's working properly for me. So I had to put my validation range tokens in another sheet(made  hidden) and I referenced  desired cell ranges from my real sheet. Here is my working code:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet realSheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet xls");
HSSFSheet hidden = workbook.createSheet("hidden");
for (int i = 0, length= countryName.length; i < length; i++) {
   String name = countryName[i];
   HSSFRow row = hidden.createRow(i);
   HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(name);
 }
 Name namedCell = workbook.createName();
 namedCell.setNameName("hidden");
 namedCell.setRefersToFormula("hidden!$A$1:$A$" + countryName.length);
 DVConstraint constraint = DVConstraint.createFormulaListConstraint("hidden");
 CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
 HSSFDataValidation validation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, constraint);
 workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
 realSheet.addValidationData(validation);
 FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\range.xls");
 workbook.write(stream);
 stream.close();
```

Comment: Great answer. I had to use "hidden!$A$1:$A$" + countryName.length to get the constraints to work.

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the same problem. Can you please provide me the output excel file using this code ? so that I can be better understand how it will work and execute the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Herin, unfortunately I worked on that project long time ago and i don't have sample output now... But here, what i'm doing is: creating an excel file with 2 sheets: 1st is actual sheet which user will see, the other is hidden used for validating the actual sheet. And then, creating a list of cells in the loop for hidden sheet, which is used for validation in actual list. 

So, if you put a 'countryName' String array at the beginning of code, it should produce an excel file which has a dropdown list with the strings from  'countryName' String array.

Comment: For newer POI versions, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27639609. For re-use of drop-down values, we can use a drop-down id as the hidden sheet name.

Comment: Greate answer! I adapted the code to work with XSSFSheet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77873854/2185783

Answer (score 3):

The formidable solution provided by Õzbek needs only slight modification to work flawlessly with NPOI (using C# on .NET).

Here's my code, provided as convenience for C# coders. It takes a sheet and positional elements as input and can also handle multiple dropdown, when they are arranged in columns.

```
public static void CreateDropDownListForExcel(this ISheet sheet, IList<string> dropDownValues, int startRow, int lastRow, int column) {
    if (sheet == null) {
        return;
    }

    //Create a hidden sheet on the workbook (using the column as an id) with the dropdown values
    IWorkbook workbook = sheet.Workbook;
    string dropDownName = sheet.SheetName + "DropDownValuesForColumn" + column;
    ISheet hiddenSheet = workbook.CreateSheet(dropDownName);
    for (int i = 0, length = dropDownValues.Count; i < length; i++) {
        string name = dropDownValues[i];
        IRow row = hiddenSheet.CreateRow(i);
        ICell cell = row.CreateCell(0);
        cell.SetCellValue(name);
    }

    //Create the dropdown using the fields of the hidden sheet
    IName namedCell = workbook.CreateName();
    namedCell.NameName = dropDownName;
    namedCell.RefersToFormula = (dropDownName + "!$A$1:$A$" + dropDownValues.Count);
    DVConstraint constraint = DVConstraint.CreateFormulaListConstraint(dropDownName);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(startRow, lastRow, column, column);
    HSSFDataValidation validation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, constraint);
    int hiddenSheetIndex = workbook.GetSheetIndex(hiddenSheet);
    workbook.SetSheetHidden(hiddenSheetIndex, SheetState.HIDDEN);

    //Add the Dropdown to the presenting sheet.
    sheet.AddValidationData(validation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, save my day. One thing, the: 
string dropDownName = sheet.SheetName + "DropDownValuesForColumn" + column;
doesn't work if the SheetName is big, better change the "DropDownValuesForColumn" for a smaller string.

Answer (score 2):

Above code works fine. But if I use XSSF classes instead of HSSF, it fails saying Exception in thread

```
"main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/poi/‌​ss/formula/FormulaParsingWorkbook;II)[Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Ptg; at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName.setRefersToFormula(XSSFName.java:195) at XLDropdown.main(XLDropdown.java:35)
```

To create dropdown list using XSSF interfaces I got the solution at

[create dropdown list using apache poi XSSF interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534095/excel-drop-down-list-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used the FormulaListConstraint using the XSSF model

```
byte[] addConstraint() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
    byte[] output = null;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

    try {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("Test.xlsx");
        InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(input, baos);
        byte[] uploadedFile = baos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedFile);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(bais);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        String originalSheet = "myhiddenSheet";
        String[] roles = new String[] { "val1", "val2"/* ...... */, "valn" };
        addHiddenSheet(workbook, roles, originalSheet);
        String formulae = originalSheet.concat("!$A$1:$A$");
        Name namedCell = workbook.createName();
        namedCell.setNameName(originalSheet);
        namedCell.setRefersToFormula(formulae + roles.length);
        XSSFDataValidationHelper userRoleDataValidationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
        XSSFDataValidationConstraint userRoleConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) userRoleDataValidationHelper
                .createFormulaListConstraint(originalSheet);
        CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
        XSSFDataValidation userStatusValidation = (XSSFDataValidation) userRoleDataValidationHelper
                .createValidation(userRoleConstraint, addressList);
        sheet.addValidationData(userStatusValidation);

        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
        output = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        workbook.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    }
    return output;
}
private void addHiddenSheet(Workbook workbook, String[] values, String hiddenSheetName) {
    Sheet hiddenSheet = workbook.createSheet(hiddenSheetName);
    for (int i = 0, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
        String name = values[i];
        Row row = hiddenSheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
    }
    workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);

}
```