# Excel Drop down list using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf

I need to create a drop down list in excel file using Apache POI. and I am able to do that so But 
I am not able to make first item in drop down list as default Item.

```java
public class sd {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

DataValidation dataValidation = null;
DataValidationConstraint constraint = null;
DataValidationHelper validationHelper = null;

 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
 XSSFSheet sheet1=(XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("sheet1");


    validationHelper=new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet1);
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new  CellRangeAddressList(0,5,0,0);
    constraint =validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"SELECT","10", "20", "30"});
    dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);      
    sheet1.addValidationData(dataValidation);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\vineet.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}

}
```

Comment: @Lucifer I am facing issue while creating large list drop-down. Is there a solution for increasing list size?

Answer (score 7):

to set a default value, just setCellValue("first_item_value");

```
sheet.getRow(1).getCell(index).setCellValue("my_default_value");
```

I have did it as facing the same problem.

Comment: But this does not comes as one of the option in the dropdownlist. What if we need it in the list? Say "SELECT" should comes as default in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("SELECT");

//2 is the 2nd cell in my case
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for creating a long dropdown list (all options combined are more than 255 characters) in an XSSFSheet which involes creating a named cell (and putting it in a hidden sheet):

```kotlin
val sheet = workbook.createSheet("mySheet")
val allowedValues = aVeryLongList()

val hiddenSheet = workbook.createSheet("hidden")
allowedValues.forEach {
    val row = hiddenSheet.createRow(hiddenSheet.physicalNumberOfRows)
    val cell = row.createCell(0)
    cell.setCellValue(it)
}

val namedCell = workbook.createName()
namedCell.nameName = "hidden"
namedCell.refersToFormula = "hidden!\$A$1:\$A$" + allowedValues.size
val validationHelper = XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet as XSSFSheet)
val constraint = validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("hidden")
val addressList = CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0)
workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true)
val dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList)
dataValidation.suppressDropDownArrow = true
dataValidation.showErrorBox = true
sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation)
```

Above code was written in kotlin and was adapted the original solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914335/2185783).