# Typeable combobox in excel file using JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to create typable combobox in the excel file (XLSX) using JAVA, where values will get filtered as user types ?

We are using Apache POI, we are able to show combobox but it is not typable. So is it possible to do it using POI or should we use any other library ?

We used sample provided in below link,

[Excel Drop down list using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534095/excel-drop-down-list-using-apache-poi)

Comment: What is the exception you get when you try to type in the combobox?

Comment: It doesn't throw exception. It is not allowing to type anything. User has to open the dropdown and select value from it.

Comment: Please add you code in your question.

Comment: Provided link of sample code we used

Comment: Can anyone please provide any solution for this ?