# Error while creating large dropdown in excel using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

This code I have written for creating large dropdown in ColdFusion, but it is not working on my end. Could any one please help me rectify my problem.  The new code is

```
    <cfquery name="getPOP" datasource="l_webalc">
    select distinct center_code from alc_pop
    </cfquery>
    <cfset countryName= ArrayNew(1)>
      <cfloop query="getPOP">
      <cfset arrayappend(countryName, getPOP.center_code)>
    </cfloop>

    <script>
      workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
      realSheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet xls");
      hidden = workbook.createSheet("hidden");

      for (int i = 0, length= countryName.length; i < length; i++) {
        String name = countryName[i];
        HSSFRow row = hidden.createRow(i);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
      }

      namedCell = workbook.createName();
      namedCell.setNameName("hidden");
      namedCell.setRefersToFormula("hidden!A1:A" + countryName.length);
      constraint = DVConstraint.createFormulaListConstraint("hidden");
      addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
      validation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, constraint);
      workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
      realSheet.addValidationData(validation);
      stream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\range.xls");
      workbook.write(stream);
      stream.close();
    </script>
```

**Update 1:**

(From [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801151/error-while-creating-validation-dropdown-in-spreadsheet-using-coldfusion)) I am getting this error message:

> function keyword is missing in FUNCTION declaration. The CFML compiler
>   was processing: A script statement beginning with HSSFWorkbook on line
>   32, column 1. A script statement beginning with function on line 31,
>   column 9. A cfscript tag beginning on line 30, column 2.

**Update 2:**

Again I have modified this code and now the new  error  is

> "The value hidden not A1:A cannot be converted to a number."

I edited the objects as mentioned in the comments and also changed the script to cfscript. Please help me to rectify this error.

```
<cfscript>
workbook = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook");
realSheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet xls");
 hidden = workbook.createSheet("hidden");
 for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(countryName); i++){
   name = countryName[i];
    row = hidden.createRow(i);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue(name);
 }
 namedCell = workbook.createName();
 namedCell.setNameName("hidden");
 namedCell.setRefersToFormula("hidden!A1:A"+arrayLen(countryName));
 dv = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.DVConstraint");
 constraint = dv.createFormulaListConstraint("hidden");
 addressList = cellRangeList.init(0, 0, 0, 0);
 validation = dataValidation.init(addressList, constraint);
 workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
 realSheet.addValidationData(validation);
  stream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\range.xls");
 workbook.write(stream);
 stream.close();
</cfscript>
```

**Update 3:**

I have updated the code to fix the mentioned issues and and am now getting this error

> "The setSheetHidden method was not found ..."

on the following line:

```
workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
```

Comment: what isn't working? Post the stack trace and error message.

Comment: your issue is probably you're using a `script` tag rather than `cfscript`

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code. Though java syntax is similar, you cannot just copy and paste a [java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655185/limitation-while-generating-excel-drop-down-list-with-apache-poi/8914335#8914335) and expect it to run in cfscript. You need to make some adjustments first. (Note: I am assuming `script` was just a typo for `cfscript`).

- In java, you can instantiate an object using the keyword "new" ie `new SomeClassName()`. In CF, the `new` keyword can only be used with cfc's. To create a java object, you must use `createObject` instead. To instantiate it, call the `init(...)` method. It is a [special method in CF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-714b.html) that invoke's the constructor of a java class with whatever parameters you supply, ie

  `createObject("java", "path.to.SomeClassName").init();`

  To use static methods such as [`DVConstraint.createFormulaListConstraint()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/DVConstraint.html#createFormulaListConstraint%28java.lang.String%29), you must also use `createObject`. While the java code does not create an `new` instance of that class, you must still use createObject to get a reference to the `DVConstraint` class, in CF, before you can invoke any of its methods. Note: Because it is static, no need to call `init()` first. ie

  `dv = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.DVConstraint");`
  `dv.createFormulaListConstraint(...);`
- Java classes are organized into [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html). In java classes, the full path to any referenced classes are imported at the top of the java code (not visible in the example you are using). In CF you need to use the full path in your `createObject` call. (Important: Paths are cAsE sEnsItIvE).

  For example, instead of `new HSSFWorkbook()` use:

  `createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook");`

  If you are not sure of the path, just do a search on "POI TheClassName". Odds are the first result will be the [POI JavaDocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddressList.html), which show the full path at the top of each page like this:

  `java.lang.Object`

  `|---org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList`
- Unlike CF, java is strongly typed, which means you must declare a variable's type as well as it's name. For example, this line declares a variable `row` as type [`HSSFRow`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html)

  `HSSFRow row = hidden.createRow(i);`

  Since CF is typeless, it does not require a type. So running that same code in cfscript will cause the cryptic error "function keyword is missing...". The solution is to drop the variable type and just do a straight variable assignment:

  `row = hidden.createRow(i);`
- [Java array indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) start at zero (0), while CF starts at one (1), so you need to fix the indexes in your for loop:

  `for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(countryName); i++)`
- Java uses `+` to concatenate strings, whereas CF uses `&`. So you need to change the operator here `"hidden!A1:A" + countryName.length`. Otherwise CF will think you are trying to add two numbers, which will obviously throw an error because the first part is a string.

Assuming no version conflicts, the java example should work after you make those those adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have modified this code.Now the error which I am getting is "The value hidden not A1:A cannot be converted to a number. "Please refer this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887786/new-type-of-error-while-creating-large-validaion-dropdown-in-excel-using-coldfus

Comment: I will take a look. BTW, that other thread is likely to be [closed as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) of this one. Better to [edit this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21870117/edit). Just add the latest code and error message to the bottom of this one (do not overwrite the original code). Then delete the other thread.

Comment: I have updated this post. Can you please check the new code from the post.

Comment: (Edit) You missed a few the `new SomeJavaClass(...)` statements. You need to convert  **all** of them to `createObject` statements. ie addressList => [`CreateCellRangeAddressList`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddressList.html) and dataValidation => [`HSSFDataValidation`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataValidation.html), and `java.io.FileOutputStream`. 2) See the last bullet point above about `+` versus `&`.

Comment: and how can I create class for fileOutPutStream.Can you please tell how will this commented code will work?

Comment: CF uses something called reflection to invoke java methods. In this case CF sees that there are two `Workbook.setSheetHidden(param1, param2)` methods, but cannot figure out which one to invoke. You want this one: [`setSheetHidden(int, boolean)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#setSheetHidden%28int,%20boolean%29), so use [`javacast`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbe.html) on the parameters to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: *RE: how can I create class for fileOutPutStream* You just need to pass in the output path, via the pseudo-constructor init() ie `createobject("java","java.io.FileOutputStream").init("c:\\path\\to\\file.xls");`

Answer (score 1):

> "The setSheetHidden method was not found ..."

Just use Javacast function for boolean arguments:

```
workbook.setSheetHidden(1, javacast("boolean",true));
```

Comment: For clarity, may as well use javacast on both arguments ie `setSheetHidden(int, boolean)`.