# string literals in formulas can't be bigger than 255 characters ascii

Tags: java, apache-poi

When there are more elements in the dropdown list in excel it shows error : 
string literals in formulas can't be bigger than 255 characters ascii

I tried creating a hidden sheet for validation constraints and real sheet for dropdown data still getting the same error.

```
private static HSSFDataValidation dropdown(int columnIndex, String[] dropdownData) {
    CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(firstRow, lastRow, columnIndex, columnIndex);
    DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(dropdownData);
    HSSFDataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(addressList, dvConstraint);
    dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
    return dataValidation;
}
```

When there is more elements in dropdown list it shows error :
string literals in formulas can't be bigger than 255 characters ascii
how to make it work using apache poi.

Comment: Does it work in Excel?

Comment: There is dropdown data for each of the column using list means I am passing the list for each of the column to make it dropdown.

Comment: @joakim yes it does work (when create dropdown manually) but using java poi it shows error when there is more data dropdown list.

Comment: I am facing this issue from last 1 week.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655185/limitation-while-generating-excel-drop-down-list-with-apache-poi. This is not a `apache poi` limitation but a `Excel` limitation. The solution is using a cell range as list source rather than a string literal.

Comment: @Alex unable to understand this example